# How to create a view for "yesterday"s data?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm partitioning my data on BigQuery by day, and I want a quick way to query "yesterday's data".

Is this possible? How can I write queries that automatically point to the latest data, without having to re-write the tables I want to query?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a view with TABLE_QUERY to find yesterday's (or an arbitrary relative date) data.

For example, GitHubArchive stores daily tables, and I created a view that points to yesterday's table:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY(githubarchive:day, 'table_id CONTAINS "events_" 
  AND table_id CONTAINS STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d")')
```

You can test and query this view:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [fh-bigquery:public_dump.github_yesterday]
```